# AWS Cloudformation Metric With Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am building Cloudwatch dashboards via Cloudformation. As far as I can tell, you cannot access any dynamic parameters while building metrics. Is this correct? Is there truly no way to dynamically specify metrics other than to hard code references? I feel like this defeats the purpose of cloudformation.

AKA something like the below to dynamically choose the region:

```
"widgets": [
    {
        "type": "metric",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 20,
        "height": 8,
        "properties": {
            "view": "timeSeries",
            "stacked": false,
            "metrics": [
                [ "LambdaFunc", "STATISTIC", { "stat": "Sum" } ]
            ],
            "title": "efficiency",
            "region": "${AWS::Region}"
        }
    },
...
```

I have tried any number of combinations/methods to reference the Cloudforamtion `AWS::Region` parameter.

Is this really it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) for that. For example:

```
MyDashboard:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
  Properties:
    DashboardName: Dashboard1
    DashboardBody: !Sub |
      "widgets": [
        {
          "type": "metric",
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "width": 20,
          "height": 8,
          "properties": {
            "view": "timeSeries",
            "stacked": false,
            "metrics": [
              [ "LambdaFunc", "STATISTIC", { "stat": "Sum" } ]
            ],
            "title": "efficiency",
            "region": "${AWS::Region}"
          }
        }
      ]
```

When using JSON templates, you usually use Fn::Sub on the result of [Fn::Join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) for easier to read formatting.